# Failed to authenticate password smtp PHP

Tags: php, smtp

After less secure password option is not available anymore I tried to implement app password in gmail however it is showing me an error:

[image]

this is my email.php configuration I am using codeigniter 3.

[image]

what I did was use my email and just paste the password in the smtp password but is not working. How can I make it work? In my local development it works fine but after deploying it to heroku it does not work anymore.

Comment: Because you dont use oauth2.0 you may enable "Access for less secure apps"; The option is available in Setting -> Security tabs -> account permissions. by the way i guess you cant use it if you already enabled two step verification.

Comment: @Debuqer I believe access for less secure app is not available anymore... I wonder why my email config works on local development but does not work when i deployed it to heroku...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 3 steps like in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357021/13633617 have been done because it seems that in the details of the question, only 1 step is done (create an app password). It worked smoothly for me.